# Flutter Model Bottom Sheet UI

Tags: flutter

```
      showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            isScrollControlled: true,
                            builder: (builder) {

                              return Container(
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: ColorConstant.whiteColor,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                width: double.maxFinite,
                                height: fem * 400,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16,20,16,0),
                                  child: Column(

                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[


                                       Row(
                                         children: [

                                         const Expanded(child: DisplayText(text: 'Filters', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,)),
                                           GestureDetector(
                                             onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                             child: const Icon(Icons.clear),),

                                       ],),

                                      const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                      const DisplayText(text: 'Practitioners', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,),
                                      const SizedBox(height: 16,),

                                      const DisplayText(text: 'Date', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,),
                                      const SizedBox(height: 8,),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 44.v,
                                        child: Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            border: Border.all(color: ColorConstant.gray300), // Silver outline
                                          ),
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            enabled: false,
                                            controller: _appointmentScreenVM.dateController,
                                            onTap: () {
                                            },
                                            decoration:  InputDecoration(
                                              suffixIcon: SvgPicture.asset(ImageConstant.calendarIcon),
                                              border: InputBorder.none,
                                            ),



                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(height: 16,),
                                      const DisplayText(text: 'Specific date range', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,),
                                      const SizedBox(height: 8,),

                                      Row(children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Column(

                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,


                                            children: [
                                            const DisplayText(text: 'From', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,),
                                            const SizedBox(height: 8,),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 44.v,
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  border: Border.all(color: ColorConstant.gray300), // Silver outline
                                                ),
                                                child: TextFormField(
                                                  enabled: false,
                                                  controller: _appointmentScreenVM.dateController,
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                  },
                                                  decoration:  InputDecoration(
                                                    suffixIcon: SvgPicture.asset(ImageConstant.calendarIcon),
                                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                                  ),



                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),


                                          ],),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(width: 16,),

                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                            const DisplayText(text: 'To', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,),
                                            const SizedBox(height: 8,),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 44.v,
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  border: Border.all(color: ColorConstant.gray300), // Silver outline
                                                ),
                                                child: TextFormField(
                                                  enabled: false,
                                                  controller: _appointmentScreenVM.dateController,
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                  },
                                                  decoration:  InputDecoration(
                                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                                  ),



                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),


                                          ],),
                                        ),


                                      ],),
                                      const SizedBox(height: 16,),

                                      CancelANdScheduledButton(
                                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.3,
                                        text: 'Reset',
                                        onTapLeftButton: () {
                                          context.pop();
                                        },
                                        subText: 'Apply',
                                        onTapRightButton: () {
                                          context.pop();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
```

I the following code I want to add a dropdown which has a list with checkbox.
[image]

My current code looks like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ListView widget beneath the DisplayText widget. This is a simple example of something you could do:

EDIT

```
List<bool> _checked = [false, false, false, ...] // Number of 
// practitioners 
DropdownButtonFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Select Items',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            items: List.generate(
              model.checked.length,
                  (index) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: index,
                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text('Item ${index + 1}'),
                    value: model.checked[index],
                    onChanged: (bool? value) {
                      // State management for checkbox selection
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            onChanged: (_) {
            // State management for dropdown selection
            },
          );
```

I do not know how you handle state management in your app but this should provide the basic functionality you are asking for.

Comment: It's not a ListView its Dropdown which has a check box.

Comment: I will update the answer with a Dropdown widget.